# How do I find the shortest unique quadkey values that appear as substrings of others in a Presto table?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table of quadkeys and I want to find the shortest unique quadkeys that are substrings of others (specifically where other values start with those quadkey values), ie the largest containing Bing tiles.  How can I go about this?  My first thought was to generate all of the possible substrings for the zoom levels I'm using, by simply creating a column for each length and looking for the shortest unique substrings, but I'm not sure how to actually execute the comparison.
Consider the following example:

I have a table that looks like this

| quadkey |
| --- |
| 121310 |
| 12131022 |
| 1213102 |
| 00321023 |
| 0032102 |

I used a query to generate the following table (which may not even be useful, but I thought it might be)

| original_quadkey | quadkey_6 | quadkey_7 | quadkey_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121310 | 121310 | NULL | NULL |
| 12131022 | 121310 | 1213102 | 12131022 |
| 1213102 | 121310 | 1213102 | NULL |
| 00321023 | 003210 | 0032102 | 00321023 |
| 0032102 | 003210 | 0032102 | NULL |

I want to keep the shortest unique values and discard rows with longer original_quadkey values that contain those "shortest unique values" as substrings.  In this case, I'd want to keep 121310 and 0032102, and to discard the rest of the rows that start with either 121310 or 0032102.  How can I query either of these tables to accomplish that goal?
I'll have to do this for millions of rows, so that potentially adds more complexity to this problem.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.quadkey
        from t t2
        where t.quadkey like t2.quadkey || '%'
        order by t2.quadkey asc
        limit 1
       ) as shortest_quadkey
from t;
```

On a large amount of data, this would have very poor performance.